# Archive encryption methods

Tags: c#, security, encryption

I am working on a simple crypting application, that is able to encrypt / decrypt one file using filestreams via Rijndael algorithm. I have one question. Lets imagine two options:

1, I create one archive (ZIP), not necessarily in my app, can be used 3rd party SW. Than encrypt it like a one file

2, I add algorithm to encrypt every file inside the selected folder tree and than create a archive from encrypted files

How big difference will be in security of the encrypted data? I know, the better way may be the second option, but how big is a difference in security?

Comment: ZIP files already support encryption.

Comment: Assuming you do proper encryption and use Encrypt-then-MAC or an AEAD algorithm, doing the whole zip file makes more sense since that authenticates the whole zip file, not just individual files, so option 1 seems better to me. If you encrypt files individually and don't protect the zip at all, an attacker can remove files or add them to the zip. I'm not sure how you reached the conclusion that #2 is better.

Comment: vcsjones: Sure, I can encrypt a archive after the process too, but my question is if unencrypted data in archive and than encrypted like a one file are same secured like a tree of encrypted files + (than encrypted like a one archive file).

Comment: @bares697: What about the filenames inside the archive?

Comment: @SLacks: Could be encrypted as well in second option, that is no such big problem. But here is the poit, if you encrypt normal archive, all is unencrypted.

Comment: "if you encrypt normal archive, all is unencrypted." I don't understand that logic. They are in the archive, and the whole archive is encrypted.

Comment: @vcsjones: So, if you create any archive (not necessarily in my app), all file names and all file content is encrypted? So why it has 7-Zip like a option?

Comment: @bares697 No, they aren't all encrypted, but you didn't mention you were working with a file other file sources.

Comment: @vcsjones: I have edited the question to be clear.